Capturing Image from Image Stream in Powershell
I have an IP camera with which I would like to capture the image every ten minutes. The camera does not expose an endpoint for a JPEG image but has a JPEG Stream endpoint. How can I capture this image in PowerShell and save it to a folder?
Note: I am in a corporate environment, and installing third-party modules or programs is not an entirely viable option

Without details about your environment I suspect no one will be able to help. As a general tip, the PowerShell cmdlets to consume web services are Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod

Without looking at your code its difficult to answer but probably what you are looking for is get-content

Get-Content reads data from a file, as text by default, and optionally as bytes. The question is about an IP camera and talks about a JPEG Stream endpoint, which suggests a web service. Therefore, it's unlikely that Get-Content will help.
